# Expressing the 2D Laplacian using information given on a parametric curve

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-derivative, laplacian

Given a planar parametric curve $C(t) = \big( x(t), y(t) \big)$ and a scalar function $u(t)$, both with $t \in [0,1]$, we can associate each point on the curve with a scalar value — for some point $P = C(t_P)$, that value would simply be $u(t_P)$. Then, we can express the *tangential derivative* of $u$ along $C$ as

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial\tau} = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{u(t + \Delta t) - u(t)}{\| C(t + \Delta t) - C(t) \|} = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{u(t + \Delta t) - u(t)}{\| \Delta t C'(t) \|} = \frac{1}{\| C'(t) \|} \frac{du}{dt},$$

where $C'(t)$ is the tangent vector to the curve. Note that $\tau(t) = \frac{C'(t)}{\| C'(t) \|}$, in other words, $\| \tau(t) \| = 1$. Likewise, for the *second-order* tangential derivative we have (updated thanks to Ted Shifrin's comments below)

$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial\tau^2} = \frac{1}{\|C'(t)\|} \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{1}{\|C'(t)\|} \right) \frac{du}{dt} + \frac{1}{\| C'(t) \|^2} \frac{d^2u}{dt^2}.$$

Now, imagine that we are also given a function $q(t) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$, that is, the *normal derivative* of $u$ along $C$, with $n(t)$ a $90^\circ$ counter-clockwise rotation of $\tau(t)$. Note that from our computed $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau}$ and the given $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$, we could compute the gradient $\big( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \big)^T$.

**My question is whether we can express the 2D Laplacian using this information.** In other words, do we have sufficient information to derive the *second-order* normal derivative $\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial n^2}$ (e.g. using the curvature $\kappa(t)$ of the curve), such that we can express

$$\Delta u = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial\tau^2} + \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial n^2} = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}$$

Comment: Where did the formula for the second derivative come from?

Comment: @TedShifrin The one for the second-order tangential derivative? The derivation is the same as for the first-order tangential derivative, it considers $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau}(t_P + \Delta t) - \frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau}(t_P)}{\| C(t_P + \Delta t) - C(t_P) \|}$.

Comment: I don’t believe it. The usual chain rule gives a $du/dt$ term unless the curve has constant speed.

Comment: @TedShifrin But do you agree with the expression for the first-order tangential derivative? This indeed simplifies to $\frac{du}{dt}$ for an arc-length parameterised curve (though this is something I do not want to assume for $C(t)$).

Comment: Yes, just do a standard chain rule computation (see, for example, section 1.2 of my differential geometry text, linked in my profile) for $U(\tau) = u(t(\tau))$, where $t(\tau)$ is the inverse function of the arclength function $\tau(t)$.

Comment: Ok, but then what is the issue with the second-order derivative? It's just another iteration of the same approach I'd say. Or to put it differently, what would be your expression for it?

Comment: Apply the chain rule and product rule rather than going back to sloppy first principles. Look at the free reference I already gave you.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah, now I see what you meant by your second comment — I should of course have applied the product rule when considering the (directional) derivative of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau}$ w.r.t. $\tau$. Thanks, I've updated it above.

Comment: To get the normal derivative as you move away from the curve, you're obviously going to need a lot more information. You also have to be very careful to have an actual local coordinate system that stays orthonormal, or else your formula for the Laplacian will get more complicated.

Comment: @TedShifrin The (first-order) normal derivative is *given*. It's the second-order normal derivative I'm looking for. As for an orthonormal coordinate system, $(\tau, n)$ should do the trick I'd say?

Comment: You need coordinates not just on $C$, but on an open neighborhood of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

The two coordinate systems $(x,y)$ and $(\tau,n)$ are both orthogonal, which is the only important thing.
So there exists an (orthogonal) rotation transformation
$$
\begin{cases}
\tau = \cos(\alpha)\,x-\sin(\alpha)\,y \\
   n = \sin(\alpha)\,x+\cos(\alpha)\,y
\end{cases}
$$
We want to know how the derivatives of the solution $\,u\,$ transform.
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} =
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial x}
+ \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\frac{\partial n}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} =
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial y}
+ \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\frac{\partial n}{\partial y}
$$
It follows, with operator notation:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u =
  \left[ \cos(\alpha)\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}
 +\sin(\alpha)\frac{\partial}{\partial n} \right] u\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} u =
 \left[ -\sin(\alpha)\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}
 +\cos(\alpha)\frac{\partial}{\partial n} \right] u
$$
So we have:
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} =
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^2 = \\
\left[\cos(\alpha)\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} +\sin(\alpha)\frac{\partial}{\partial n} \right]^2
+ \left[ -\sin(\alpha)\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}+\cos(\alpha)\frac{\partial}{\partial n} \right]^2 = \\
\left[\cos^2(\alpha)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}\right)^2 +
2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial}{\partial n}
+\sin^2(\alpha)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\right)^2\right] + \\
\left[\sin^2(\alpha)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}\right)^2
-2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}\frac{\partial}{\partial n}
+\cos^2(\alpha)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\right)^2\right] = \\
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\right)^2 =
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \tau^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial n^2}
$$
Therefore $\Delta u$ is the same in the (global) plane coordinates as well as in the (local) curve coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some slight imprecisions of definition here (in particular I would argue that $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial n^2}$ is not well defied), but it's quite clear that what you're asking for is impossible, as the following counterexample demonstrates:

Let $C(t)=(t,0)$ be a parameterization of the $x$-axis, and define $u_1(x,y)=0$ and $u_2(x,y)=y^2$. One can see that $u_1\circ C=u_2\circ C$ and $\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial n}\circ C=\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial n}\circ C$, so all of the "given" information is the same between the two functions. Nonetheless, their Laplacians do not agree along $C$, i.e. $\Delta u_1\circ C\neq\Delta u_2\circ C$. This means that the Laplacian along $C$ is not uniquely determined by the "given" information.

Comment: But $u$ is only given along $C(t)$, not as $u(x,y)$. The same goes for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$. In some sense, it's similar to prescribing both Dirichlet *and* Neumann boundary conditions to a planar curve.

Comment: @Ailurus By "$u$ is only given along $C$", I presume you mean that $u\circ C$ is given, while $u$ itself is unknown. This is precisely the interpretation I was using.

Comment: What is given are $C(t)$, $u(t)$ and $q(t) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$, all with $t \in [0,1]$. Note that $u(t)$ and $q(t)$ are both scalar-valued and independent of each other. I suppose we could define the scalar values of $u$ and $q$ along $C(t)$ as $u \circ C^{-1}$ and $q \circ C^{-1}$, with $C^{-1}$ mapping a point $P = C(t_P)$ back to $t_P$.

Comment: @Ailurus When you write $q(t)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$, you seem to be implicitly assuming that there is an unknown function $u:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $u(t)=u(C(t))$. Rather than using $u$ to denote both functions, I used $u$ to denote the unknown function $u(x,y)$, and $u\circ C$ to denote the known function $u(t)$.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the example you gave. Still trying to wrap my head around cases with a curved $C(t)$ and/or non-zero $u(t)$ and q(t)$ though.

Comment: @Ailurus It's false in that case as well, but the counterexamples are more cumbersome to construct.